# Maas 2.8 and Windows image

Tags: maas

I'm working on Windows server image work on Maas 2.8, but I'm getting many issues to do that.
I'm able to upload the image to the Maas Region and sync it with the Rack controller, but during the deployment, in the first boot, the deployment fail.

Command that I'm using to upload the image.

```
sudo maas $profile boot-resources create name=windows/win2012r2 architecture=amd64/generic filetype=tgz title=windows2012v3 content@=/home/user/windows-win2012r2-amd64.raw.tgz

The image looks available to deploy, this is the output of the image deployment. 

curtin: Installation started. (19.3-26-g82f23e3d-0ubuntu1~18.04.1)
third party drivers not installed or necessary.
start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: curtin command block-meta
get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda
Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
devsync for /dev/sda
Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.039
devsync happy - path /dev/sda now exists
return volume path /dev/sda
get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda-part1
get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda
Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
devsync for /dev/sda
Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.047
devsync happy - path /dev/sda now exists
return volume path /dev/sda
get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda-part2
get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda
Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
devsync for /dev/sda
Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.046
devsync happy - path /dev/sda now exists
return volume path /dev/sda
Declared block devices: ['/dev/sda']
start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta/clear-holders: removing previous storage devices
Running command ['mdadm', '--assemble', '--scan', '-v'] with allowed return codes [0, 1, 2] (capture=True)
mdadm assemble scan results:
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
Running command ['mdadm', '--detail', '--scan', '-v'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=True)
mdadm detail scan after assemble:
Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.013
Running command ['pvscan', '--cache'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Running command ['vgscan', '--mknodes', '--cache'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Running command ['vgchange', '--activate=y'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Loading kernel module bcache via modprobe
Running command ['modprobe', '--use-blacklist', 'bcache'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
devname '/sys/class/block/sda' had holders: []
Current device storage tree:
sda
Shutdown Plan:
{'level': 0, 'device': '/sys/class/block/sda', 'dev_type': 'disk'}
shutdown running on holder type: 'disk' syspath: '/sys/class/block/sda'
Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
get_blockdev_sector_size: info:
{
 "sda": {
  "ALIGNMENT": "0",
  "DISC-ALN": "0",
  "DISC-GRAN": "0",
  "DISC-MAX": "0",
  "DISC-ZERO": "0",
  "FSTYPE": "",
  "GROUP": "disk",
  "KNAME": "sda",
  "LABEL": "",
  "LOG-SEC": "512",
  "MAJ:MIN": "8:0",
  "MIN-IO": "512",
  "MODE": "brw-rw----",
  "MODEL": "Virtual disk    ",
  "MOUNTPOINT": "",
  "NAME": "sda",
  "OPT-IO": "0",
  "OWNER": "root",
  "PHY-SEC": "512",
  "RM": "0",
  "RO": "0",
  "ROTA": "1",
  "RQ-SIZE": "128",
  "SIZE": "53687091200",
  "STATE": "running",
  "TYPE": "disk",
  "UUID": "",
  "device_path": "/dev/sda"
 }
}
get_blockdev_sector_size: (log=512, phys=512)
Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Checking if /dev/sda is a swap device
Found swap magic: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
wiping superblock on /dev/sda
wiping /dev/sda attempt 1/4
wiping 1M on /dev/sda at offsets [0, -1048576]
successfully wiped device /dev/sda on attempt 1/4
devname '/sys/class/block/sda' had holders: []
finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta/clear-holders: SUCCESS: removing previous storage devices
blockmeta: detected dd-images, using mode=simple
Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
installing in 'custom' mode to 'sda'
writing image to disk {'type': 'dd-tgz', 'uri': 'http://172.20.0.2:5248/images/windows/amd64/generic/win2012r2/uploaded/root-dd'}, sda
Running command ['sh', '-c', 'wget "$1" --progress=dot:mega -O - |tar -xOzf -| dd bs=4M of="$2"', '--', 'http://172.20.0.2:5248/images/windows/amd64/generic/win2012r2/uploaded/root-dd', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
--2020-07-16 15:28:43--  http://172.20.0.2:5248/images/windows/amd64/generic/win2012r2/uploaded/root-dd
Connecting to 172.20.0.2:5248... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-07-16 15:28:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.0767571 s, 0.0 kB/s
Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.033
Searching for filesystem on ['sda'] containing one of: ['curtin', 'system-data/var/lib/snapd']
Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
TIMED BLOCK_META: 1.374
finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: curtin command block-meta
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/curtin/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
    ret = args.func(args)
  File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return log_time("TIMED %s: " % msg, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 79, in log_time
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 84, in block_meta
    return meta_simple(args)
  File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 1886, in meta_simple
    rootdev = write_image_to_disk(dd_images[0], devname)
  File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 127, in write_image_to_disk
    return block.get_root_device([devname], paths=paths)
  File "/curtin/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 587, in get_root_device
    (dev, paths))
ValueError: Did not find any filesystem on ['sda'] that contained one of ['curtin', 'system-data/var/lib/snapd']
Did not find any filesystem on ['sda'] that contained one of ['curtin', 'system-data/var/lib/snapd']
curtin: Installation failed with exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['curtin', 'block-meta', 'custom']
Exit code: 3
Reason: -
Stdout: start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: curtin command block-meta
        get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda
        Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
        lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
        lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
        Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        devsync for /dev/sda
        Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
        Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.039
        devsync happy - path /dev/sda now exists
        return volume path /dev/sda
        get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda-part1
        get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda
        Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
        lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
        lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
        Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        devsync for /dev/sda
        Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
        Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.047
        devsync happy - path /dev/sda now exists
        return volume path /dev/sda
        get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda-part2
        get_path_to_storage_volume for volume sda
        Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
        lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
        lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
        Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        devsync for /dev/sda
        Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=False)
        Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.046
        devsync happy - path /dev/sda now exists
        return volume path /dev/sda
        Declared block devices: ['/dev/sda']
        start: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta/clear-holders: removing previous storage devices
        Running command ['mdadm', '--assemble', '--scan', '-v'] with allowed return codes [0, 1, 2] (capture=True)
        mdadm assemble scan results:
        
        mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
        mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
        mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda
        mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop0
        mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
        
        Running command ['mdadm', '--detail', '--scan', '-v'] with allowed return codes [0, 1] (capture=True)
        mdadm detail scan after assemble:
        
        
        Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.013
        Running command ['pvscan', '--cache'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        Running command ['vgscan', '--mknodes', '--cache'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        Running command ['vgchange', '--activate=y'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        Loading kernel module bcache via modprobe
        Running command ['modprobe', '--use-blacklist', 'bcache'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        devname '/sys/class/block/sda' had holders: []
        Current device storage tree:
        sda
        Shutdown Plan:
        {'level': 0, 'device': '/sys/class/block/sda', 'dev_type': 'disk'}
        shutdown running on holder type: 'disk' syspath: '/sys/class/block/sda'
        Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        get_blockdev_sector_size: info:
        {
         "sda": {
          "ALIGNMENT": "0",
          "DISC-ALN": "0",
          "DISC-GRAN": "0",
          "DISC-MAX": "0",
          "DISC-ZERO": "0",
          "FSTYPE": "",
          "GROUP": "disk",
          "KNAME": "sda",
          "LABEL": "",
          "LOG-SEC": "512",
          "MAJ:MIN": "8:0",
          "MIN-IO": "512",
          "MODE": "brw-rw----",
          "MODEL": "Virtual disk    ",
          "MOUNTPOINT": "",
          "NAME": "sda",
          "OPT-IO": "0",
          "OWNER": "root",
          "PHY-SEC": "512",
          "RM": "0",
          "RO": "0",
          "ROTA": "1",
          "RQ-SIZE": "128",
          "SIZE": "53687091200",
          "STATE": "running",
          "TYPE": "disk",
          "UUID": "",
          "device_path": "/dev/sda"
         }
        }
        get_blockdev_sector_size: (log=512, phys=512)
        Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        Checking if /dev/sda is a swap device
        Found swap magic: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        wiping superblock on /dev/sda
        wiping /dev/sda attempt 1/4
        wiping 1M on /dev/sda at offsets [0, -1048576]
        successfully wiped device /dev/sda on attempt 1/4
        devname '/sys/class/block/sda' had holders: []
        finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta/clear-holders: SUCCESS: removing previous storage devices
        blockmeta: detected dd-images, using mode=simple
        Processing serial 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6 via udev to 6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6
        lookup_disks found: ['wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6', 'scsi-36000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6']
        lookup_disks realpath(wwn-0x6000c29a8d35a6c739a39d8d0deafcc6)=/dev/sda
        Running command ['udevadm', 'info', '--query=property', '--export', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        installing in 'custom' mode to 'sda'
        writing image to disk {'type': 'dd-tgz', 'uri': 'http://172.20.0.2:5248/images/windows/amd64/generic/win2012r2/uploaded/root-dd'}, sda
        Running command ['sh', '-c', 'wget "$1" --progress=dot:mega -O - |tar -xOzf -| dd bs=4M of="$2"', '--', 'http://172.20.0.2:5248/images/windows/amd64/generic/win2012r2/uploaded/root-dd', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        --2020-07-16 15:28:43--  http://172.20.0.2:5248/images/windows/amd64/generic/win2012r2/uploaded/root-dd
        Connecting to 172.20.0.2:5248... connected.
        HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
        2020-07-16 15:28:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.
        
        
        gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
        tar: Child returned status 1
        tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
        0+0 records in
        0+0 records out
        0 bytes copied, 0.0767571 s, 0.0 kB/s
        Running command ['partprobe', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        Running command ['udevadm', 'settle'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
        TIMED udevadm_settle(): 0.033
        Searching for filesystem on ['sda'] containing one of: ['curtin', 'system-data/var/lib/snapd']
        Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/sda'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
        TIMED BLOCK_META: 1.374
        finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: curtin command block-meta
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
            ret = args.func(args)
          File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 97, in wrapper
            return log_time("TIMED %s: " % msg, func, *args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/log.py", line 79, in log_time
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 84, in block_meta
            return meta_simple(args)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 1886, in meta_simple
            rootdev = write_image_to_disk(dd_images[0], devname)
          File "/curtin/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 127, in write_image_to_disk
            return block.get_root_device([devname], paths=paths)
          File "/curtin/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 587, in get_root_device
            (dev, paths))
        ValueError: Did not find any filesystem on ['sda'] that contained one of ['curtin', 'system-data/var/lib/snapd']
        Did not find any filesystem on ['sda'] that contained one of ['curtin', 'system-data/var/lib/snapd']
        
Stderr: ''
```

Comment: Does anyone know if to use Windows image is it needed to contract Ubuntu support?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the curtin hooks are installed in the image and that the image upload in maas is done like this:

```
maas root boot-resources create name=windows/win2012r2 architecture=amd64/generic filetype=ddtgz content@=/home/maasctrl/windows-win2012r2-amd64-root-dd
```

(note that you must use that specific name and filetype for this to work).

Ref: [Problem deploying WinSrv2019 Image with MaaS](http://ask.cloudbase.it/question/3097/problem-deploying-winsrv2019-image-with-maas/).